# Make PhpStorm show changed/modified files in project view

Tags: phpstorm

After moving from Zend Studio (ZS) to PhpStorm, I am starting to miss the way that ZS used to show changed files and display more than one project at once.

For example, notice how it shows that IndexController.php has been modified.

Is there any way to do this with PhpStorm?

[image: Zend Studio PHP Explorer]

Comment: You mean -- VCS status? If so -- it shows -- using different colors. But it shows only on the actual file and not on parent folders: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html

Comment: @LazyOne do you know if it is possible to also highlight the parent folders?

Comment: @Simon Not in current version. But it is already implemented for v6 (122.xx branch). If you really want to see it in action now -- you can try their Intellij IDEA v12 (all-in-one) -- the public EAP builds already have it: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP . Otherwise wait for v6 -- public EAP program should start in couple of weeks (or sooner).

Comment: @LazyOne: v6 is released, but it only highlights the direct parent folder, not ALL parent folders. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: @Simon **Settings | Version Control | Show directories with changed descendants** -- that's the only option. If it does not work for you then I do not know any other one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Go to** file >> settings >> Editor >> General >> Editor Tabs.
**Check** Mark modified tabs with asterisk
**Click** ok

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking. That option just puts an asterisk in tab titles for unsaved files, but it doesn't highlight which files in the project were actually modified.

Comment: I was actually looking how to do it in WebStorm but this got  me close enough. In WebStorm 9 (on Windows), if anyone is wondering, it is: File -> Settings->Editor->General->Editor Tabs and then select "Mark modified tabs with asterisk". On Mac it is: Preferences->Editor->General->Editor Tabs.

Comment: this does not answer the question the answer below by (divoto) does

Answer (score 35):

**Starting from PhpStorm 2022.1:**

To highlight folders containing `vcs` changed files enable:

**File | Settings | Version Control | Confirmation | Highlight directories that contain modified files in the Project tree**

*Older versions:*

As [mentioned in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483227/make-phpstorm-show-changed-modified-files-in-project-view#comment21821264_11483227) by [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone);

The `Project` panel does highlight any `VCS` changes,
but to also highlight all parent-folders of changed-files, enable:

**File | Settings | Version Control | Show directories with changed descendants**

All kudos to [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone)!

Comment: I cannot achieve some behaviour which is similar. I want to mark directories with ADDED files to RED, same as mark for ADDED files. I cannot find such option. If someone have some suggestion, I'll be glad.
  
    
  
I'm using sass with compass and sometimes sass is creating new files for me (but these files are not added to git repository). Files are listed and marked on red, but not parent directories.  
  

Modified files parents are colored as expected.

Comment: It does not work for tab `Project Files` but works for tab `Project`. Thank you!

Comment: To customize Changed Files color : `Appearance & Behavior` => `File Colors` => `Local colors` => `Add a color label` (plus sign on right) = > `Scope` select `Changed Files` => select a background color. To customize changed files tree colors : `Version control` => `File Status Colors` => `Have changed descendant` and `Have immediate changed children`

Comment: I cannot see a "Version Control" heading in settings. Has it been deleted, moved or ...

Answer (score 29):

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd> (not from `numpad`) you can get a panel with the changed files.

Comment: this definitely shows what eclipse users are after, but it is in an entirely different panel

Comment: It might not be perfect, but it's closer than the accepted answer, which does something entirely different to what was asked in the original question. Why was that even accepted?

Comment: the true answer is your answer, the tick is right on you.

Comment: Nope does nothing here.

Comment: Try pressing Cmd+E or Ctrl+E and then check "Show changed only". You can also click the "Project" dropdown in the left side panel and select "All changed files".

Comment: I don't have the Local Changes tab here only the Log one, I used to have it on Linux but not on Windows any clue how to get it back?

Comment: To answer my own question, there was a change in 2020.1, in the settings search for "non modal" and untick the first result, to get back this tab, probably would be a good addition to this answer

Answer (score 4):

For PhpStorm version 2022.1.2, on MacOS Big Sur, you will need to go to:
Preferences -> Version Control -> Confirmation, then under Changes you will need to check the "Highlight directories that contain modified files in the Project tree" box.

Comment: Yes, that's it for newer PhpStorm versions! (Not only on MacOS)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

To be more specifically. Under File Status (settings)
[option] Have changed descendants
[option] Have immediate changed children
[option] Modified

Change this three color

Comment: If not work, try this
If not work, try this
File | Settings | Version Control | Show directories with changed descendants

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm store all the changes on your file. If you use Git or VCS it is easy to see what changes you have, but this is also availabe for normal local projects.
Open:

```
VCS -> Local History -> Show History
```

[image]

You will see the big windows divided on 2. Left showing all the versions, right all the modified files. Double click also gives you a diff windows, showing diference between both files.

All The modificationas are shown as a scalar one, means that selecting left the top one will show just last modification. Selecting in left the scond will show agregated modification since this time.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Well u deserved an up tick after all this time. I keep asking how to see changed files, I keep forgetting and keep looking it up again - so thanks! Oh to be young again! (Or mot)

Answer (score 1):

As in PhpStorm 2021 you can achieve it by going to **Settings > Version Control > Git** and check **Enable Staging Area**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for solution:

Go to `View` & look for `Changes` option, it should bring up the tree view of changes for current project.
You can also do `show diff with current working tree` in VSC pane.

Answer (score 0):

In a Git toolbar (ctrl+9) tab named Local changes

[image]